# Question about reference types

Tags: c#, reference

This is taken from Jon Skeet's excellent personal C# site (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/):

```
StringBuilder first = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder second = first;
first.Append ("hello");
first = null;
Console.WriteLine (second);
```

1) Changing the value of first will not change the value of second -

2) although while their values are still references to the same object, any changes made to the object through the first variable will be visible through the second variable.

This is taken from the same sentence. What is meant by changing the value? I assume the value of a variable (eg int x = 4, or 5, or 45, etc).

Does this mean if first points to another compatible object, it won't have an effect on two?

Everything on that page makes sense, I think it's just an issue with my interpretation of the English.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first` is a reference to an object of type `StringBuilder`. That is, `first` stores a value that can be used to refer to an object on the heap that is type of `Stringuilder`. `second` is another reference to an object of type `StringBuilder` and its value is initially set refer to the same object that `first` is referring to.

If you change the value of `first` what you are doing is changing what the referent is. That is, you are using `first` to refer to a different object. This does not impact `second`; its value is unaffected by changes to the value of `first`. (Remember: the value of `first` and `second` are references that initially have the same referent. But just like with

```
int x = 1;
int y = x;
x = 2;
```

does not change the value of `y`, changing the value of `first` does not change the value of `second`.

On the other hand, when `first` and `second` refer to the same object, any changes to that object will be visible through both `first` and `second`.

Think of it like this. Let's say I create a text file `first.html` whose contents are

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

and I issue the command `copy first.html second.html`. Then both pages can be used to refer to the same webpage; by following the link we arrive at the same referent. If changes are made to the Stack Overflow home page, then accessing the homepage through either `first.html` or `second.html` will allow me to see those changes. But if I then change the contents of `first.html` to be

```
<a href="http://www.thedailywtf.com>The Daily WTF</a>
```

then I can no longer use `first.html` to refer to the Stack Overflow homepage. Moreover, this change does not impact the value of `second.html`. It is still

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com>Stack Overflow</a>
```

Think of the contents of these files as the values of a reference type, and the ultimate desination as the referent object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the value of the object itself and the contents of the object are not clear.

For example, it is possible to change the contents of second by calling methods on first, as in the call to Append in the example. However, setting the value of first to null does not set second to null.

You can see this easily by writing this code and stepping through it in a debugger.

Comment: I see. "Value" would mean like its state - e.g. null, which, if first is set to, doesn't effect second. The contents of first, however, do effect second.

Comment: I'd consider it unwise to refer to "state" in this fashion; an object's state is contained within an object itself, and changes to such are thus visible through all references. You run the risk of confusing yourself or others later.